# .htaccess redirects : posting the subsequent uri

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website set up where I store all my user profiles in /member-centre/member-directory/*USERNAME*

My problem is that a number of referrals are posting to a depreciated structure of /members/*USERNAME*

Is there a way I can configure my .htaccess file to automatically post the requested *USERNAME* to the correct location? All i've found on google is static redirection.

If this is not possible through .htaccess, is there another method I could use?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a redirect solution, Jon Lin's will work fine. If you want to do a rewrite then put the following in your .htaccess file in the root of your domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/members/([^/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . member-centre/member-directory/%1 [L]
```

if member/centre etc is relative to the root filesystem and not your domain then replace the last line with (just leading slash)

```
RewriteRule . /member-centre/member-directory/%1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go into extra detail Ulrich - You've increased my understanding greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/members/([^/]+)/? /member-centre/member-directory/$1
```

This redirects the browser with a permanent redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^members/ /member-centre/member-directory/ [L]
```